Chrome controlled by Chromedriver silenced alert popup
I used the following html to test an alert pop up. If a user fills the form, but then switches URL, instead of submitting the form, the page will pop up an alert
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="#">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" onchange="updateFname()">
            <button class="submit-btn" onclick="return false;">
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let fname = '';
        updateFname = () => {
            fname = document
                .getElementById('fname').value;
        }
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload',
            function (e) {
                if (fname !== '') {
                    console.log("form is filled but not submitted yet");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.returnValue = '';
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

When I tested the page in chrome alone, the alert popped up as expected

But when I run Selenium with ChromeDriver and Chrome, Chrome didn't pop up the alert and switched the URL directly.

The old Chrome and Chromedriver (version under 100 worked fine. Alert popped up).
My Chrome and Chromedirver version is 131.
Is there a way to make the alert pop up again?
Thank you
UPDATE:
this is how I started my Selenium -> Chromedriver -> Chrome
driver_service = ChromeDriverService(
    executable_path=self.driver_exe,
    log_path=self.driverlog,
    service_args=self.driver_args,  # for chromedriver
)

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=driver_service,
    options=self.browser_options,
)

I dumped the Chrome options and Chromedriver options
    browser_options.arguments = ['--user-data-dir=C:/Users/xxx/selenium_browser',
 '--window-size=1260,720',
 '--disable-gpu',
 '--enable-javascript',
 '--disable-extensions',
 '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
 'enable-automation',
 '--disable-browser-side-navigation']

driver.args = ['--verbose']


Can you put options to the Chromedriver?

please see my update. thank you

Try to add --disable-popup-blocking option browser_options.arguments

It didn't work - alert didn't pop up. thank you

Sorry, then I do not know, what's the issue. Does beforeunload get called?

yes. I can see "form is filled but not submitted yet" in devtool's console log
